# Should I use char array instead of String for usernames of players?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, char

I am making an app, and I have a User class with a final username, email, and password. I read that object creation can slow down an app, so would it be good practice to convert these fields to char arrays instead? My logic is that a bunch of these Strings may slow down the app if I have, say, a million users.

Comment: A `char[]` is an object, same as `String`. Before Java 9 (or 10?) a `String` stored the content as a `char[]` anyway (now it stores the content as a `byte[]`). Bonus: `String` is immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You would be falling into the trap of *premature optimization*.

Use regular `String` objects to hold name and such.

If you were to manage text yourself you would have to learn that a [`char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) type is outmoded and can hold less than half of the 137,000 characters defined by Unicode. So you would have to learn how to handle the char array as [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) using quad-[octets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)) rather than double-octets when representing characters outside the [Basic Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) range of characters. So you would learn about recognizing high and low [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) values as mapping to other code points. And even if you managed all that, your `char` arrays would not be benefitting from the innovations of things like [*JEP 254: Compact Strings*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) and [*JEP 280: Indify String Contcatenation*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280) as discussed in [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIyeOaitmWM&feature=youtu.be).

Lesson to learn here: **Do not try to outsmart the Java team and the JVM** without being *very* educated about the technical details *and* having a proven need so severe as to require such intervention. Your app is best served by **writing simple code using the obvious classes**, and letting the compiler and JVM do their job to optimize.

Modern JVM implementations are *highly* optimized. You need not worry about the burden of object creation except in the most extreme conditions.

And even then you need to prove and diagnose the problem with profiling and debugging tools before jumping at a solution. Even the brightest of programmers have been shown to be notoriously bad at preventing/solving supposed performance problems.

Furthermore, you tagged your question as Android. You have only one user on an Android app, not a million. If you were referring to your server-side coding, when you get to a million users you will have a long list problems to concern you. `String` versus `char[]` for user name will not be high on that list.

Comment: Thank you. Can you point me in the direction of server-side coding? (This app is very much "server-based")

Comment: @JTalbott That is much too broad a subject for a Comment. You’ll need to do your own searching and study.